# SQL or operator how to use with having

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, operator-keyword

i have a table which i am joining with with operator. I can have 2 combinations id that table FDEL - 1 or 0 and FDVE 1 or 0, what i would like to do is to dispay if - item has fdve, or item has fdel (and count) but it doesnt work (i can see all fdve, or all fdel) [image]

```
select
    lpad(purchase_id,10,0) as purchase_id,
   sum(has_label_fdel) as FDEL_count,
    case when  LABELS   like '%FDVE%' then 1 else 0 end as HAS_LABEL_FDVE,
    sum(has_label_fdve) as FDVE_count
 from 
    "SRC_ORACLEIWP"."PURCHASE_ANALYSIS_RULES"
    group by
    lpad(purchase_id,10,0),has_label_fdve
    
having  FDVE_count>0 -- FDEL_count>0
```

Comment: What is your DBMS? Are you using MySQL? And you want one result row per product? And a product in your table can sometimes have `has_label_fdel` and sometimes `has_label_fdve` and you want to count the occurences per product? (E.g. product 12345 has five fdel entries and seven fdve entries in the table, so show 12345 | 5 | 7?)

Comment: Hello its snowflake, and yes sometimes can be fdel, sometimes fdve a want to count occurance in delivery, as i am using group by

Comment: Your query makes it look like there is one column called `labels` and it contains a text that may contain the substring '%FDVE%' (and maybe the substring '%FDEL%', too?), but also a column called `has_label_fdel` and a column called `has_label_fdve`. Is this really the case? This looks redundant and rather unlikely to me.

Comment: Yes, as I said i am joining this within another selects, so this %FDEL_ is choosen from Json parse. But this is unrelevant to issue, thing i would like to do is just count in both columns and show it

Comment: `having  FDVE_count>0 OR FDEL_count>0 ` ??

Comment: so, basically a comination of [HAVING](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/having.html) and [OR](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/operators-logical.html)

Comment: @Luuk having  FDVE_count>0 OR FDEL_count>0  this i have tried first but id didnt work

Comment: @saska: "it does not work" is a useless statement, please provide FULL error messages (in TEXT, not in PICTURES)

Comment: from the [HAVING](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/having.html) page, I draw the conclusion that this should work: `having  sum(has_label_fdel)>0 OR sum(has_label_fdve)>0`

Comment: @luuk - please apologise, there is no error statement, but its not counting FDVE labels so thier sum is 0 which i know is not correct

Comment: @luuk - having  sum> 0 this seems to be working I need to integrate into that huge select but looks like relevant idea to me, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want one resut row per product, so group by product only. Use `SUM`for counting and `MAX` for the aggregated yes/no.

```
select
  lpad(purchase_id,10,0) as padded_purchase_id,
  max(has_label_fdve) as has_labels_fdve,
  sum(has_label_fdve) as fdve_count,
  max(has_label_fdel) as has_labels_fdel,
  sum(has_label_fdel) as fdel_count
from src_oracleiwp.purchase_analysis_rules
group by padded_purchase_id
having has_labels_fdve = 1
    or has_labels_fdel = 1
order by padded_purchase_id;
```

I've changed your alias names slightly, so they are digfferent from the columns you have (because such ambiguities can sometimes lead to problems).

The check on `labels like '%FDVE%'` is unnecessary, because you already have the `has_label_fdve` flag, which is always 0 or 1. Or so it seems. If the flags can be null, use `COALESCE` on them or do use `LIKE` expressions.

If you don't have `has_label_fdve` and `has_label_fdel` yet, use the `labels` column instead:

```
select
  lpad(purchase_id,10,0) as padded_purchase_id,
  max(case when labels like '%FDVE%' then 1 else 0 end) as has_labels_fdve,
  sum(case when labels like '%FDVE%' then 1 else 0 end) as fdve_count,
  max(case when labels like '%FDEL%' then 1 else 0 end) as has_labels_fdel,
  sum(case when labels like '%FDEL%' then 1 else 0 end) as fdel_count
from src_oracleiwp.purchase_analysis_rules
group by padded_purchase_id
having has_labels_fdve = 1
    or has_labels_fdel = 1
order by padded_purchase_id;
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunatelly it does not work as this case when was important because it selected label from Json parse, so it does not work at all - as now there is no column has_label_fdve or fdve count

Comment: Then you answered my question incorrectly. I asked you if you had lhe columns `labels` and `has_label_fdve` redundantly. I've added the same query based on the `labels` column.